# Solve the partial equation $(y-u)u_x+(x-y)u_y=u-x$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

By Lagrange by adding all the equations we have
$dx+dy+dz=0$ implies $x+y+z=c_1$

but i couldn't get any other useful equation .

Comment: Are there supposed to be subscripts there?

Comment: Yes but I don't know how to do that

Comment: @nedkelly https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanx a lot @Gary

Comment: Sorry for that @Gary

Answer (score 1):

$$(y-u)u_x+(x-y)u_y=u-x$$
$$\frac{dx}{y-u}=\frac{dy}{x-y}=\frac{du}{u-x}=\frac{dx+dy+du}{(y-u)+(x-y)+(u-x)}=\frac{dx+dy+du}{0}$$
A first characteristic from $dx+dy+du=0$ :
$$x+y+u=c_1\quad\implies\quad u=-x-y+c_1$$
A second characteristic from $\frac{dx}{y-u}=\frac{dy}{x-y}=\frac{dx}{y-(-x-y+c_1)}$

Solving $\quad\frac{dy}{x-y}=\frac{dx}{2y+x-c_1}\quad$ is for you.

After solving replace $c_1$ by $(x+y+u)$.

Comment: Thanks for your effort @jjacquelin